# Setting default Ruby version outside RVM

Tags: ruby, path, rvm

When I input:

```
ruby -v
```

I get:

```
ruby 1.8.7
```

but with:

```
rvm list
```

I get:

```
=* ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

What is causing this mismatch? How do I correct it so I always use 2.2.1?

Comment: Your configuration is likely wrong. See https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: It sounds like your path is not set correctly. Append the output of `rvm info` to your question, formatted for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess there is something wrong with your `$PATH` and you are referencing the system ruby maybe? I would recommend double checking the [install directions](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).

You could also try running again:

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Finally, once you get that working, I also find using `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` files in repos/folders very helpful. See "[Typical RVM Project Workflow](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects#project-file-ruby-version)" for more info.

Comment: The problem was coming stemmed from usage of pantheon terminal which was not allowing me to run as login-shell from startup. The fix was to install gnome terminal and change this setting. I got there from going down to the bottom of the install directions so that was the key. Thanks